# FFMPEG Determine average color of an area of a video

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg

I have a use case where I'd want to insert one of two watermarks - one designed for a dark-ish background, the other for a light background into a video. Let's say that I'd want to do this on the top right corner of the video.

How do I determine the average color of the top right section of the video? Post this, how do I determine which watermark to use by looking at the average color?

I have a solution right now where I am taking equally spaced screenshots and then measuring the average color, but it's excruciatingly slow, especially for longer videos.

```
# Calculate average color
    black_distances = []
    white_distances = []

    movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(video_file)
    (0..movie.duration / 10).each do |second|

      # extract a frame
      filename = "tmp/watermark/#{SecureRandom.uuid}.jpg"
      movie.screenshot filename.to_s, seek_time: second

      # analyse frame for color distance
      frame = MiniMagick::Image.open(filename)
      frame.crop('20%x20%+80%+0')
      frame.resize('1x1')
      pixel = frame.get_pixels.flatten

      distance_from_black = Math.sqrt(((black[0] - pixel[0])**2 + (black[1] - pixel[1])**2 + (black[2] - pixel[2])**2))
      distance_from_white = Math.sqrt(((white[0] - pixel[0])**2 + (white[1] - pixel[1])**2 + (white[2] - pixel[2])**2))

      black_distances.push distance_from_black
      white_distances.push distance_from_white

      File.delete(filename) if File.exist?(filename)
    end

    average_black_distance = black_distances.reduce(:+).to_f / black_distances.size
    average_white_distance = white_distances.reduce(:+).to_f / white_distances.size
```

I am also confused about how to use the resulting `average_black_distance` and `average_white_distance` to determine which watermark to use.

Comment: Some little suggestions, maybe they'll make the procedure faster:

a) create a directory, put all pictures extracted from the video in the directory, and do an `rm -rf` after everything is done.
b) omit the `Math.sqrt` because it doesn't affect the result.
c) sum up `distance_from_white - distance_from_black` (actually the squared distances), if it's positive, then the area is more on the bright side.
d) maybe you can handle only the keyframes and ignore other frames (needs proof).
e) maybe using [cumo](https://github.com/sonots/cumo) can leverage your CUDA compatible graphic card.

Comment: Just use the signalstats filter in ffmpeg and examine the avg Y (luma).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this faster by doing the following:

1. Taking screenshots using a single ffmpeg command, instead of iterating over movie.length and taking an individual shot every x seconds.
2. Cropping and scaling the screenshot in the same ffmpeg command, instead of doing that with MiniMagick.
3. Deleting with `rm_rf` instead of doing so inside the loop.

```
    # Create folder for screenshots
    foldername = "tmp/watermark/screenshots/#{medium.id}/"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p foldername

    # Take screenshots
    movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(video_file)
    `ffmpeg -i  #{video_file} -f image2 -vf fps=fps=0.2,crop=in_w/6:in_h/14:0:0,scale=1:1 #{foldername}/out%d.png`

    # Calculate distances
    white = Color .new('#ffffff')
    black = Color .new('#000000')
    distances = []
    Dir.foreach foldername do |f|

      next if %w[. .. .DS_Store].include? f

      f = MiniMagick::Image.open(foldername + f)
      color = f.get_pixels.flatten

      distance_from_black = Color.new(color).color_distance(white)
      distance_from_white = Color.new(color).color_distance(black)

      distances.push distance_from_white - distance_from_black
    end
```

If the value of `distances.inject(0, :+)` is positive, the video area captured is on the brighter side. Thanks to @Aetherus!